# JRuby: how to call a Java variadic function without optional arguments

Tags: jruby, variadic-functions, argument-error

I have a function with a signature similar to `String.format(String, Object...)`.

I want to call this function from JRuby without the last parameters (since it is optional), but my code throws an `ArgumentError` (`wrong # of arguments(1 for 2)`)

Is there a way to call this function with only 1 argument just like I would do in Java?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, is there some way to do optional arguments in Java aside from method overloading (i.e., multiple same-named methods with different params)?

Comment: I don't think so. Aside from method overloading and variadic functions, I see no other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the varargs into a Java array

```
  jruby-1.4.0 > java.lang.System.out.format('foo %d, %d, %d, %d, %d', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].to_java)
  foo 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 => #<Java::JavaIo::PrintStream:0x79ef3ccd>
```

If all you want is to skip the varargs, pass an empty Java array instead

```
  jruby-1.4.0 > java.lang.System.out.format('foo ', [].to_java)
```

Comment: I already figured I could do that. What I want is being able to call the method without the array argument. Currently, I am 
re-opening every class by hand to change the method signature.

Comment: I don't think it is possible for Jruby to do that for you automatically - look at their bugtracker, there was a mention of this specifically